# Is there a way to fix the provider used by Vagrant?

Tags: vmware, vagrant, vmware-fusion

When using Vagrant I can specify other providers by using the `--provider` argument. Alas, this is quite tedious if you have to type it again and again:

```
$ vagrant up --provider vmware-fusion
```

Is there a possibility to configure *once* that vagrant should *always* use the given provider, unless I specify something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` environment variable ([docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/default.html)). For example in *.profile* or alike:

```
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER="vmware_fusion"
```

If you want to set it for a specific project, you should be able to set it in Vagrantfile:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = "vmware_fusion"

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...
end
```

The provider can be overridden with the CLI option.